# Does Amazon EC2 support LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#-3.0, amazon-ec2

Does amazon ec2 support Linq to sql or not?

Comment: what do you mean by 'Linq to SQL'?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. I can give you a very definitive answer because we are right now using both LINQ-to-SQL and Amazon EC2 (!) for our startup http://LabSlice.com. In practice Amazon just gives you the machines, so you can install anything you want on it if you wish to enable things like LINQ-to-SQL. Note that I'm using only Win2k8+SQL instances for the startup, so other images may not support your requirements out of the box.